# How to understand the following Crontab? i know the structure but can't find proper source to clearly explain it

Tags: python, cron, putty

I am just trying and working with cron jobs for the first time and need some context into how to create a pattern i need.

just need an explanation with an example. thanks.

```
m     h  dom mon dow
35   */8  *   *   * 
9,35   *  *   *   *
47     6  *   *   7
52     6  1   *   *
```

Comment: See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html#EXAMPLE_CRON_FILE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is explanation:

```
35   */8  *   *   *
```

run 35t minute every 8 hours: 0,8,16

```
9,35   *  *   *   *
```

run every 9 and 35 minute, every hour, every day

```
47     6  *   *   7
```

run at 6:47 on sundays

```
52     6  1   *   *
```

run at 6:52 every 1st day of every month